# Como calculo usando onblur entre 3 campos

Tags: javascript, onblur

Eu tenho 3 campos num form. Colocando o valor em um, ao sair deste campo, o lavascript deve fazer o calculo e popular os outros dois cada um com um resultado:

EX:

```
Campo 1: Entro com o valor 10
Ao sair do campo 1, deve fazer
Campo 2 = Campo1 * 10 / 100
Campo 3 = Campo1 * 20 / 100
```

Tem como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com jquery agiliza o processo...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.input1').blur(function(e){
                    var inp1 = $(this).value;

                    var inp2 = (inp1 * 10)/100;
                    var inp3 = (inp1 * 20)/100;

                    $('.input2').val(desconto);
                    $('.input3').val(total);
                })
            })
```

Comment: OK. Resolvido. Obg.

Comment: `$(this).value;` devia ser `$(this).val()` e seria melhor converter para tipo _Number_.